# I would like to set up a subdomain for my website that redirects to my discord invite link

Tags: domains, redirects, wordpress, subdomain, links

Is there a way to Set a subdomain on my website to redirect to my discord invite? Is it possible and is it allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand this you would need to set up a subdomain to point to a link that you own, and then either do a redirect to the invite link or embed it in an iframe.

I've only skimmed their terms and conditions but I see nothing therein preventing you from doing a redirect. Their terms may preclude you from legally going the iframe route.

Comment: This Worked! Thank you.

Comment: @LeviPopken-Webb, if DavidGo's answer was useful, please accept it